80's fantasy movie with an extremely fast furry creature

The movie was live-action.
It was most probably fantasy, but could have also been s-f.
I've watched it on VHS between 1989 and 1994, so it was most probably from the 80's.
I don't remember any details regarding the language spoken.
The protagonist was a young man and part of the plot involved him trying to attack a castle.
In his quest he was aided by a small group of furry humanoids. They were human-size and all from one race, tribe or something similar.
Later the protagonist was joined by a hermit-like bearded old man after his group came to the hermit's hut.
The hermit had a pet or friend, which was a small (about 1 m tall) humanoid furry creature. I think it couldn't speak, but communicated with the hermit in some other way. It had white or yellowish fur and could run extremely fast. The speed was so high that its movement appeared blurry.
I remember a scene where the whole group is walking through a plain towards the castle and the fast creature is sent for reconnaissance.


Hmm... is it possible that it's Ewoks: The Battle for Endor?

In his quest he was aided by a small group of furry humanoids.

Did they look like:


The hermit had a pet or friend, which was a small (about 1 m tall) humanoid furry creature.



Looks like I didn't remember the protagonist and the castle attack part very well, but that's definitely what I was looking for. Funny thing is that I remembered the furry humanoids as ewoks, but I thought it's my memory playing tricks :-) Thanks a lot!
